# How can I use $app in custom classes in Silex?

Tags: php, silex

I know this looks like a dupllicate of [Inject Silex $app in my custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565709/inject-silex-app-in-my-custom-class) and others, but I couldn't get it working from their solutions.

I define my service like this:

```
$app['user.repo'] = function () {
    return new MyApp\Repository\User();
};
```

My class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Repository;
use Silex\Application; 

class User {
    public function findAll(Application $app) {
        $users = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user');
        return $users;
    }
}
```

And I use the service like this:

```
$users = $app['user.repo']->findAll($app);
```

How can I do this same thing without putting `$app` in all my methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you inject it?

```
$app['user.repo'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new MyApp\Repository\User($app);
};
```

And here's your modified class:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Repository;
use Silex\Application; 

class User {
    /** @var Application */
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app) {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function findAll() {
        $users = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user');

        return $users;
    }
}
```

Or even better: instead of injecting the whole application (and thus hiding your real dependencies, making unit testing a pain), only inject what you really need:

```
$app['user.repo'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new MyApp\Repository\User($app["db"]);
};
```

This way your class becomes:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Repository;
use Silex\Application; 

class User {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findAll() {
        $users = $this->db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user');

        return $users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Before I tried injection and almost used the same exact solution... I just lack understanding of classes and basic PHP. I had `$db->fetchAll(..)` instead of `$this->db->fetchAll(...)`.